# Copy/Paste visible row whith hidden/filtered rows

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste, hidden

I try to add a function which can copy/paste a visible row, inserting a new one in the same table.
It works pretty well but not anymore with hidden rows.
Error message :

> "This operation does not work with ranges where one line is filtered."

Would it be possible to solve it ?

```
function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

Comment: You need to say which language and software you are using. We cannot tell from the example alone without more details.

Comment: It's Apps Script for Google Sheet. I found formula :

Answer (score 0):

I found a formula that works well:

```
function copypasteRow() {
  var active_range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  active_range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```